# Creating dummy variables in SAS from a categorical variable

Tags: loops, macros, sas, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I am looking to create dummy variable for a categorical variable in SAS. The categorical variable includes information on sites and takes on values such as Manila, Rabat etc., all in all there are about 50 different sites. What would be the most efficient way to create dummies without creating each dummy separately using "if then"? Maybe using loops? How would that look like

Comment: Please provide more information. What does you data look like specifically? Provide sample data of what you have and what you want.  What values does dummy take on ?  Are you looking to have the categorical values become column names (any of transpose, tabulate, report/across)  Show the code of the if/thens that you have written and are dis-satisfied with

Comment: What are you doing with your data once you've created the dummy variables? Many procs within SAS support the use of a `class` statement, which effectively creates dummy variables for you behind the scenes.

Comment: the site variable takes on nominal values and ideally I would like to create a separate column for i.e. Berlin which will be a binary variable, Hamburg (0,1) etc.. I want to run a logistic regression where I believe the Site variable to be an important independent variable. As I said, the site variable takes on about 50 different nominal values and I am looking where I can create a command that says to create a dummy for each of these possible values for the variable Site. Is there a shortcut or do I have to create 50 variables separately?

Comment: Here's a write up I did a while back that illustrates one method and the links below illustrate several other methods. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Statistical-Procedures/How-to-create-dummy-variables-Categorical-Variables/td-p/258702

Answer (score 0):

short answer: yes. Without further input I'm afraid there is little we can provide. here are a few examples:

```
data with_categoric(keep=category:);
    set sashelp.zipcode; 
    category1 = (TIMEZONE='Central' and length(COUNTYNM) <=4); 
    if      35>Y then category2='low'; 
    else if 35<Y<41 then category2='medium'; 
    else category2='high'; 
run;
```

An alternative way to do the Category2 is via `proc format`:

```
proc format; 
    value level 
    low-35 = 'low'
    35-41 = 'med'
    41-high ='high';
quit;

data W_proc_foramt; 
    set sashelp.zipcode; 
    levelled = Y; 
    format levelled level.; 
run;
```

Your can check more from [Documentation](http://support.sas.com/publishing/pubcat/chaps/63671.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create the dummy category is to use the  observation number as a suffix.

Solution:

```
/*Create Table with 5 Records*/
data input;  
input Category $40.;  
cards;  
A 
B 
C 
D 
E 
;;;; 
run; 
/*Create dummy categories using "_N_" record number as suffix */
data work.dummy;
set work.input;
dummy= catx("-","CAT",put(_N_,8.));
put _all_;
run;
```

Output:

```
Category=A dummy=CAT-1 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
Category=B dummy=CAT-2 _ERROR_=0 _N_=2
Category=C dummy=CAT-3 _ERROR_=0 _N_=3
Category=D dummy=CAT-4 _ERROR_=0 _N_=4
Category=E dummy=CAT-5 _ERROR_=0 _N_=5
```

Comment: Can you please check this as an accepted solution if it answered your question? Thanks

Comment: I used the class statement within the logistic regression: proc logistic data=WORK.DUMMY OUTEST=betas covout;
class FLOW SITE RISK /param=ref; 
model Y = FLOW SITE RISK OTHERS / selection=stepwise; run: My problem with it is that it creates a reference level and all the dummies only make sense in comparison to the reference level. After running this, I only picked the dummy variables that are significant and separately created dummies for them and left the insignificant ones out. Is that an accepted procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to convert categorical into dummy variable in SAS and run linear regression, but did not find one place with all answers, so I will put here the result of my search.
Say we have a dataset (mydata) with dependent variable Y and categorical variables A1,A2...An. Each idependent variable has X1,X2...Xm valid values. e.g.:

```
A1 | A2 | A3
---|----|---
x1 | y1 | z1
x2 | y1 | z2
x1 | y2 | z3
```

The output after dummy conversion would be:

```
A1x1 | A1x2 | A2y1 | A2y2| A3z1| A3z2 | A3z3
-----|------|------|-----|-----|------|-----
 1   |  0   |  1   |  0  |  1  |  0   |  0
 0   |  1   |  1   |  0  |  0  |  1   |  0
 1   |  0   |  0   |  0  |  0  |  0   |  1
```

The code to accomplish the conversion to dummy is:

```
DATA mydata;
   set mydata;
   dummy=1;
RUN;
PROC logistic data=mydata  outdesignonly  outdesign=design;
   CLASS A1 A2 A3/param=glm;
   MODEL dummy=A1 A2 A3;
RUN; 
DATA  mydata_dummy;
  merge mydata(drop=dummy)   design(drop=dummy intercept);
RUN;
DATA  mydata_dummy;
   SET mydata_dummy;
   DROP A1 A2 A3;
RUN;
```

The side effect of covnerting categorical variables into dummy variables, is the inflation in varibale names.
To avoid listing all new column names (e.g. for REG) 
You cannot use (MODEL Y=*all*) because Y will be also in *all*

Instead of.

```
MODEL Y=A1x1 A1x2 A2y1 A2y2 A3z1 A3z2  A3z3
```

Do the following:

```
PROC CONTENTS data=mydata_dummy noprint out=_contents_; 
RUN;
PROC sql noprint;
  SELECT name into :names separated by ' ' 
  from _contents_ where upcase(name) ^='Y';
RUN;

PROC reg DATA=mydata_dummy;
    MODEL Y=&names;
RUN;
```

....Thanks

Comment: Hello, Great answer. I have a question, If there is Id column how to keep it in the logistic procedure step?

Comment: PROC LOGISTIC data=... OUTEST=... PLOTS=all DESCENDING;
   ID your_id_column;
   CLASS your_categroical_columns;
   MODEL .......

Comment: Thanks again for the answer!!